# JavaScript heap out of memory (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a problem, my Java Script runs out of memory and i dont know why.
Memory usage jumps to almost 2gB when I start the code.
Currently if i comment out this part of my code it works fine:

```
var way = [];
for(var x = 0;x<=way1.length > way2.length?way1.length:way2.length;x++){
    way.push(way1[x]);
    way.push(way2[x]);
}
```

otherwise it will crashe.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Without looking deeply in the code. Why the hell do you have such complex expression inside the for? That is probably your issue

Answer (score 3):

The expression inside the loop does not do what you think it does.

```
x <= way1.length > way2.length? way1.length : way2.length
```

What you probably meant

```
x <= (way1.length > way2.length? way1.length : way2.length)
```

It actually does

```
(x <= way1.length > way2.length) ? way1.length : way2.length
```

Which always return the same number. Either way1.length or way2.length - which is always true. And the loops goes infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is very confusing, and is most probably producing a wrong result, maybe you should do

```
var way = [];
for(var x = 0, length = Math.max(way1.length, way2.length); x <= length; x++){
    way.push(way1[x]);
    way.push(way2[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the loop condition first, I think condition making your program out of memory

Comment: Ok, i´ll try it.